# Uikit center navigation

Tags: html, uikit

```
<nav class="uk-navbar">
    <div class="uk-container uk-container-center">
        <a href="#" class="uk-navbar-brand"><img src="images/logo.png" 
  alt="AlminasLogo"/></a>

        <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
            <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Pagrindinis</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Paslaugos</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Atsiliepimai</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Apie</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Kontaktai</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="uk-navbar-flip">
            <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
                <li><a href=""><i class="uk-icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href=""><i class="uk-icon-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

This is my code sample, and here is the result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JIL0.jpg

As you can see, the `navbar` is centered, but `navbar-flip` isn't. Why is that and how to center it? Both of them are already contained in `uk-container-center`....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested your code (I don't have the logo), and the result is what you pretend.

I imagine your logo must be what is pushing everything down in the first `div`!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.4/css/uikit.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/uikit/2.27.4/js/uikit.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <nav class="uk-navbar">
    <div class="uk-container uk-container-center">
      <a href="#" class="uk-navbar-brand"><img src="images/logo.png" alt="AlminasLogo" /></a>

      <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
        <li class="uk-active"><a href="#">Pagrindinis</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Paslaugos</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Atsiliepimai</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Apie</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Kontaktai</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="uk-navbar-flip">
        <ul class="uk-navbar-nav">
          <li><a href=""><i class="uk-icon-facebook"></i></a></li>
          <li><a href=""><i class="uk-icon-instagram"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Ps: Next time, please provide everything in English and without inaccessible code (example: `images/logo.png`). Your question and my answer should apply to everyone, not only your case ;)